# How to calculate number of classes in a project

Tags: c#, vb.net, class, vb6

We are dealing with VB6 and .NET project and need to calculate the number of classes.

For vb6 we sum up the total number of standard and class modules which gives us the total number of classes in project.

For .NET we calculate the total number of code behind files, and in standalone .vb or .cs files we calculate the number of classes defined inside. This total is considered as final count.

Is this correct? or in .NET is the standalone .vb or .cs file supposed to be considered as 1 class rather than counting the classes inside this file??

Comment: It is a best practice to only have 1 class in a code file but it is not required to do it that way

Comment: We have one .vb file which has got 12 classes. I thought that one .vb file itself is an class file. Because you rightclick project and select add class file? Isnt it? Then how come you can define more classes within a class file?

Comment: Do you have to calculate it on the runtime or statically? If statically, you can use code metrics in VisualStudio. (Analyze -> Caluculate Code Metrics for Solution). It shows also other additional useful informations. The only drawback is that metrics shows only used class (defined but not used anywhere is not counted).

Comment: Which version of VS shows the Analyze option?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think any above Express Edition (if missing, there is a plugin for VisualStudio - but Express Edition doesn't support plugins).

Comment: Do you think we should calculate the codebehind file (.vb or .cs) of a form as a class file?

Comment: It depends. Sometimes codebehind file is partial class, so one class is splitted into two or more files.

Comment: No partial classes. For example should the file1.aspx.vb be considered as a class if it is codebehind of file1.aspx?

Comment: how do users create object in such a case where in with in the class file (.cs or .vb) there are more classes defined?? Do they say filename x=new filename(); or do they say: ClassNameInsideFilename x = new ClassNameInsideFilename();?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`For .NET we calculate the total number of code behind files, and in standalone .vb or .cs files we calculate the number of classes defined inside. This total is considered as final count.`

`Is this correct? or in .NET is the standalone .vb or .cs file supposed to be considered as 1 class rather than counting the classes inside this file??`

No you cannot be sure that counting files can reveal total number of classes.

**Reason**

1. There can be more than one class in a .cs or .vb file. Although it is a good practice to have only one class in a code file but .Net does not restrict you to have more than one class in a file.

2. A class can exist in multiple files through the use of `partial` keyword in C# and `Partial` keyword in VB.Net.

Hence always count the distinct names of classes in .Net.

Comment: Is'nt the .cs or .vb itself a class file. Then why does .NET allow developers to define more classes within this class file?

Comment: Now, how do users create object? Do they say filename x=new filename(); or do they say: ClassNameInsideFilename x = new ClassNameInsideFilename();?

Comment: @variable: For first question: Look at .cs or .vb as textfile which have your code. You can write anything in it. Its your IDE that validates the content and now where in any IDE we have right now restricts you do not have more than 1 class.

Comment: Can you answer Q2 please.

Comment: @variable: For second question: Its always `ClassName cn = new ClassName();` irrespective of where this class is.

Answer (score 10):

with `Reflection` you can get the number of classes on a specific namespace, somthing like this help me ones :

```
int num = (from cal in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
           where cal.Namespace == "ProjNameSpace" && cal.IsClass
           select cal).ToList().Count();
```

or

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain
         .GetAssemblies()
         .SelectMany(cyp => typ.GetTypes())
         .Where(cal => cal.IsClass && cal.Namespace == "ProjNameSpace")
         .ToList().Count();
```